# Is there a correct column specification I should be following for this sklearn transformer?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have been trying this section of code block which runs except the last section. I am creating Pipelines to perform certain transforms such as StandardScaler(), and OrdinalEncoder(), and so on. Yet when I got to the column transformer fit transformer it gave me an error.

```
file1_train = file1_train.drop(columns = ["PassengerId","Name"])
file1_train

objs = file1_train.select_dtypes(["object"])
num  = file1_train.select_dtypes(["number"])

objs.isnull().sum().head()

num.isnull().sum().head()

numerical_features = file1_train[num.columns]
numerical_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
            ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')),
            ("scaler", StandardScaler())
    ]
)

for i in range(len(objs.columns)):
    print(objs.columns[i], objs.iloc[:,i].value_counts().unique())

binary = file1_train["Sex"]
binary_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("binary", LabelBinarizer())
    ]
)

cat1 = file1_train[["Ticket", "Cabin", "Embarked"]]
catergorical_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
            ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
            ("ordinal_encoder", OrdinalEncoder()),
            ("scaler", StandardScaler())
    ]
)

data_preprocessor   = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers = [
        ('numerical', numerical_pipeline, numerical_features),
        ('binary', binary_pipeline, binary),
        ('categorical', catergorical_pipeline, cat1)
    ])
Y = file1_train.pop("Survived")

X = file1_train

X_transform, Y_transform = data_preprocessor.fit_transform(X,y=Y)
```

This is the following error code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6bc00e8acc58> in <module>
     43 X = file1_train
     44 
---> 45 X_transform, Y_transform = data_preprocessor.fit_transform(X,y=Y)

~\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    504         self._validate_transformers()
    505         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 506         self._validate_remainder(X)
    507 
    508         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

~\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    322 
    323         # Make it possible to check for reordered named columns on transform
--> 324         self._has_str_cols = any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
    325                                  for cols in self._columns)
    326         if hasattr(X, 'columns'):

~\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    322 
    323         # Make it possible to check for reordered named columns on transform
--> 324         self._has_str_cols = any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
    325                                  for cols in self._columns)
    326         if hasattr(X, 'columns'):

~\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _determine_key_type(key, accept_slice)
    266         except KeyError:
    267             raise ValueError(err_msg)
--> 268     raise ValueError(err_msg)
    269 
    270 

ValueError: No valid specification of the columns. Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed
```

I have imported all the necessary modules and can be shown as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplplt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow.keras.callbacks
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelBinarizer, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.utils import resample
```

I have tried renaming the columns and changing how I named them but it has been to no effect.